# Measure high impedance with low internal impedance device

Tags: high-impedance

I was given this thought by one of my co-workers (we're both still novices when it comes to electronics). Background: we have a device with a small internal impedance and have to measure a high impedance device. Would an op amp acting as a voltage follower followed by a voltage divider to measure the high input impedance work with the small output impedance device?

Hopefully that's not too confusing. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Unclear: Does your device under test have a high output or input impedance? Please specify each device with high/low impedance and input/output direction.

Comment: The DUT is a passive component. I think I edited the question correctly

Comment: It is still not clear to me. What do you mean by internal impedance? Please provide some kind of drawing.